# Не компилируется вторая jsp страница , проблема связана с getAttribute(). Использую tomcat9

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Не компилируется вторая jsp страница , проблема связана  с getAttribute(). Использую tomcat9

Задание в том, чтобы вернуть площадь треугольника и его координаты на вторую jsp страницу

Лог ошибки[image: Лог ошибки]

---

Сам сервлет

```
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;


//@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/TestWebApp/*"})
public class TestWebApp extends HttpServlet {


    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        try {
            super.init(servletConfig);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("firstpage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        double x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3;
        String XorY = req.getParameter("X1");
        x1 = Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        XorY = req.getParameter("Y1");
        y1 = Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        XorY =req.getParameter("X2");
        x2 = Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        XorY = req.getParameter("Y2");
        y2 = Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        XorY = req.getParameter("X3");
        x3 = Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        XorY = req.getParameter("Y3");
        y3 =Double.parseDouble(XorY);
        if (((x1 == x2)&&(x2==x3)&&(x3==x1))||((y1==y2)&&(y2==y3)&&(y3==y1))){
          req.getRequestDispatcher("firstpage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else{
        double dist12, dist23, dist13;
        dist12 = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
        dist23 = Math.sqrt((x2-x3)*(x2-x3) + (y2-y3)*(y2-y3));
        dist13 = Math.sqrt((x1-x3)*(x1-x3) + (y1-y3)*(y1-y3));
        double p = (dist12 + dist23 + dist13)/2;
        double Square =  Math.sqrt(p*(p-dist12)*(p-dist23)*(p-dist13));
        String x1s,x2s,x3s,y1s,y2s,y3s,Squares;
        x1s = Double.toString(x1);
        x2s = Double.toString(x2);
        x3s = Double.toString(x3);
        y1s = Double.toString(y1);
        y2s = Double.toString(y2);
        y3s = Double.toString(y3);
        Squares = Double.toString(Square);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("X1s", x1s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("X2s", x2s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("X3s", x3s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Y1s", y1s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Y2s", y2s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Y3s", y3s);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Squares", Squares);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("secondpage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
      }
    }


}
```

---

перваЯ jsp страница

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Square of triangle</title>
    <style>
 body {
  background: #c7b39b url(images/background.png); /* Цвет фона и путь к файлу */
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/TestWebApp" method = "post" id ="sendd">
<h1 align = "middle">Square of trinagle</h1>
 <p align = "middle"><img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="triforce"></p>
<p align = "middle"><b>Enter first coordinate:</b><br>
  <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
    <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="X1" placeholder="Enter X1">
    <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
      <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="Y1" placeholder="Enter Y1">
  <p align = "middle"><b>Enter second coordinate:</b><br>
    <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
      <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="X2" placeholder="Enter X2">
      <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
        <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="Y2" placeholder="Enter Y2">
    <p align = "middle"><b>Enter third coordinate:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
        <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="X3" placeholder="Enter X3">
        <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
          <input align = "middle" type="text" size="40" required type="text" name="Y3" placeholder="Enter Y3">
           <p align = "middle"><button type="submit" form="sendd">Send coordinates</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

вторая jsp страница

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher,javax.servlet.ServletConfig,java.util.*, java.text.*,java.io.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Square of triangle</title>
    <style>
 body {
  background: #c7b39b url(images/background.png); /* Цвет фона и путь к файлу */
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align = "middle">Square of trinagle</h1>
 <p align = "middle"><img src="images/pic.jpg" alt="triforce"></p>
<p align = "middle"><b>First coordinate:</b><br>
  <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
  <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("X1s")%></p>
    <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("Y1s")%></p>
  <p align = "middle"><b>Second coordinate:</b><br>
    <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("X2s")%></p>
      <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
        <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("Y2s")%>oordinate:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><b>X:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("X3s")%></p>
        <p align = "middle"><b>Y:</b><br>
      <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("Y3s")%></p>
              <p align = "middle"><b>Square of triangle:</b><br>
              <p align = "middle"><%=req.getSession().getAttribute("Squares")%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если заменить скриптлеты на ЕЛ выражения, то может и зарабоьает

Answer (score 0):

Ваш второй jsp не знает что такое `req`. Надо бы объявить